# JSON Schema Validator Selecting Validators

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

My problem is how do I get the [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) library to actually validate a JSON response against the JSON Schema I have defined. My goal is to get "additionalProperties" and field type checking working. I.e. have the validation reject unknown fields and check that numerics don't contain strings etc.

Files, code and background information follow.

**Schema** [Swagger 2.0](http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#) standard definition

**Schema Students** API Defintion

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Students API",
    "description": "Operations on Students",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "basePath": "/v1/students",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json",
    "application/xml"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/{UID}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "students"
        ],
        "summary": "Get information about a Students Member.",
        "description": "Given an University ID, return information for the identified students member.",
        "operationId": "getStudentsByUID",
        "produces": [
          "application/xml",
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "required": true,
            "name": "UID",
            "in": "path",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK. The operation was successful.",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Students"
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content. No Students the UID"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Not Authorised"
          },
          "405": {
            "description": "Method Not Allowed"
          },
          "429": {
            "description": "Too Many Requests"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Students": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "Status": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Status"
        },
        "Person": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Person"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Status": {
      "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "StatusCode": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Reason": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "StatusCode",
        "Reason"
      ]
    },
    "Person": {
      "type": "object",
      "description": "Representation of a person record for a student",
      "properties": {
        "PersonIdentifiers": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Identifier": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Identifier"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "PersonNames": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/PersonNames"
        },
        "AcademicPlanDetails": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "AcademicPlanDetail": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/AcademicPlanDetail"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Identifier": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "IdentifierType": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "IdentifierValue": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "PersonNames": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "FirstName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "MiddleName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "LastName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Title": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Mr",
            "Mrs",
            "Ms",
            "Master",
            "Dr"
          ]
        },
        "NameSuffixes": {
          "description": "Not applicable to all Persons",
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Jr",
            "CPA",
            "Esq",
            "Ph.D"
          ]
        },
        "FullName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "PreferredName": {
          "description": "Not applicable to all Persons",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "LongName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AliasName": {
          "description": "Not applicable to all Persons",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Pronunciation": {
          "description": "Not applicable to all Persons",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "AcademicPlanDetail": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "AcademicCareer": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "StudentCareerNumber": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "EffectiveDate": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "EffectiveSequence": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AcademicProgram": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AcademicProgramDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AcademicPlan": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AcademicPlanDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AcademicSubPlan": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AcademicSubPlanDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ProgramStatus": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ProgramStatusDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ProgramAction": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ProgramActionDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ProgramReason": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ProgramReasonDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AdmittedTerm": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ResearchStudentCandidateNumber": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "api-metadata",
      "description": "Information about the API including its terms of use"
    },
    {
      "name": "students",
      "description": "Operations on all types of University students"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Students Response Good** Valid response message

```
{
  "Status": {
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Reason": "OK",
  },
  "Person": [
    {
      "PersonIdentifiers": {
        "Identifier": [
          {
            "IdentifierType": "UniversityID",
            "IdentifierValue": "12345678"
          },
          {
            "IdentifierType": "EmailAddress",
            "IdentifierValue": "JohnSmith@no.such.org"
          },
          {
            "IdentifierType": "PositionNumber",
            "IdentifierValue": "00006789"
          }
        ]
      },
      "PersonNames": {
        "PreferredName": "",
        "FirstName": "Johnathon",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "Smith",
        "Title": "Dr",
        "NameSuffixes": "",
        "FullName": "Smith,Jonathon",
        "LongName": "",
        "AliasName": "",
        "Pronunciation": ""
      },
      "AcademicPlanDetails": {
        "AcademicPlanDetail": [
          {
            "AcademicCareer": "RSCH",
            "StudentCareerNumber": "0",
            "EffectiveDate": "2019-12-19",
            "EffectiveSequence": "1",
            "AcademicProgram": "9876",
            "AcademicProgramDescription": "Arts & Social Sciences",
            "AcademicPlan": "9876XPHD",
            "AcademicPlanDescription": "School of Humanities and the Arts",
            "AcademicSubPlan": "HUMAN",
            "AcademicSubPlanDescription": "Humanities",
            "ProgramStatus": "AC",
            "ProgramStatusDescription": "Active",
            "ProgramAction": "MATR",
            "ProgramActionDescription": "Matriculate",
            "ProgramReason": "ACTV",
            "ProgramReasonDescription": "Activated Manually",
            "AdmittedTerm": "1903",
            "ResearchStudentCandidateNumber": "000000034567"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Students Response Bad** Invalid response message. Includes unwanted aggregates, fields and wrong data types.

```
{
  "Fred": {
    "Freddy": "Kruger"
  },
  "Status": {
    "StatusCode": "200",
    "Reason": "OK",
    "X-Event-Id": "12340818-5a7c-11ea-920e-0a2835080000-1",
    "Unexpected": "Undefined additional propery"
  },
  "Person": [
    {
      "PersonIdentifiers": {
        "Identifier": [
          {
            "IdentifierType": "UniversityID",
            "IdentifierValue": "12345678"
          },
          {
            "IdentifierType": "EmailAddress",
            "IdentifierValue": "JohnSmith@no.such.org"
          },
          {
            "IdentifierType": "PositionNumber",
            "IdentifierValue": "00006789"
          }
        ]
      },
      "PersonNames": {
        "PreferredName": "",
        "FirstName": "Johnathon",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "Smith",
        "Title": "Dr",
        "NameSuffixes": "",
        "FullName": "Smith,Jonathon",
        "LongName": "",
        "AliasName": "",
        "Pronunciation": ""
      },
      "AcademicPlanDetails": {
        "AcademicPlanDetail": [
          {
            "AcademicCareer": "RSCH",
            "StudentCareerNumber": "0",
            "EffectiveDate": "2019-12-19",
            "EffectiveSequence": "1",
            "AcademicProgram": "9876",
            "AcademicProgramDescription": "Arts & Social Sciences",
            "AcademicPlan": "9876XPHD",
            "AcademicPlanDescription": "School of Humanities and the Arts",
            "AcademicSubPlan": "HUMAN",
            "AcademicSubPlanDescription": "Humanities",
            "ProgramStatus": "AC",
            "ProgramStatusDescription": "Active",
            "ProgramAction": "MATR",
            "ProgramActionDescription": "Matriculate",
            "ProgramReason": "ACTV",
            "ProgramReasonDescription": "Activated Manually",
            "AdmittedTerm": "1903",
            "ResearchStudentCandidateNumber": "000000034567"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code** JSON Schema and JSON Instance validation

```
package com.nsd;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.ProcessingException;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingReport;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory;


public class JsvCmd {
    public static final String JSON_V4_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER = "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#";
    public static final String JSON_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER_ELEMENT = "$schema";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ProcessingException {
        final JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();

        // Load the JSON Schema for Swagger 2.0 API definition
        File swaggerSchemaFile = new File("/Users/syntegrity/Documents/AnuStuff/Swagger2.0.json");

        JsonNode jsonNodeSwagger = JsonLoader.fromFile(swaggerSchemaFile);
        JsonNode schemaIdentifierSwagger = jsonNodeSwagger.get(JSON_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER_ELEMENT);
        if (null != schemaIdentifierSwagger) {
            System.out.println("Swagger Schema Type: " + schemaIdentifierSwagger.asText());
        }

        final JsonSchema jsonSchemaSwagger = factory.getJsonSchema(jsonNodeSwagger);

        // Next load the schema we are interested in and validate it against the Swagger 2.0 API schema
        File userSchemaFile = new File("/Users/syntegrity/Documents/AnuStuff/Students_V1_SO.json");

        JsonNode jsonNodeUserSchema = JsonLoader.fromFile(userSchemaFile);

        ProcessingReport userSchemaReport = jsonSchemaSwagger.validate(jsonNodeUserSchema, true);
        if (!userSchemaReport.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("UserSchema is invalid");
            System.out.println(userSchemaReport);

            return;
        }

        // To get the validators we want used happening add a $schema element that specifies IETF Draft-04
        JsonNode schemaIdentifierUser = jsonNodeUserSchema.get(JSON_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER_ELEMENT);
        if (null == schemaIdentifierUser) {
            ((ObjectNode) jsonNodeUserSchema).put(JSON_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER_ELEMENT, JSON_V4_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER);

            System.out.println("User Schema coerced to IETF Draft-04 for validation purposes");
        } else {
            // For what we want to do anything other than a $schema value of IETF Draft-04 is going
            // to cause problems. NOTE: The Swagger 2.0 API schema does not allow $schema anyway
            if (!JSON_V4_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER.equals(schemaIdentifierUser.asText())) {
                System.out.println("Schema Type: " + schemaIdentifierUser.asText() + " is not " + JSON_V4_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER);

                return;
            }
        }

        JsonSchema jsonSchemaUser = factory.getJsonSchema(jsonNodeUserSchema);

        // Finally validate the JSON data
        File jsonDataFile = new File("/Users/syntegrity/Documents/AnuStuff/Students_Bad_SO.json");
        JsonNode jsonNodeData = JsonLoader.fromFile(jsonDataFile);

        ProcessingReport userDataReport = jsonSchemaUser.validate(jsonNodeData, true);

        if (!userSchemaReport.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println(userDataReport);
        } else {
                System.out.println("Sweet");
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nsd</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsvcmd</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>JsonValidator</name>
    <description>JSON Validator Command Line</description>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.oai/swagger-request-validator -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-coreutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Run Results**

```
Swagger Schema Type: http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#
User Schema coerced to IETF Draft-04 for validation purposes
Sweet
```

I was hoping to see the following errors rather than "Sweet"

- Unwanted: [Fred]
- Unwanted: [X-Event-Id]
- Unwanted: [Unexpected]
- "200" is not of type integer

**Debugging**

If I change **"produces"** to **"producesx"** in the **Students Schema** the I get the following output.

```
UserSchema is invalid
com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ListProcessingReport: failure
--- BEGIN MESSAGES ---
error: object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: ["producesx"]
    level: "error"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":""}
    instance: {"pointer":""}
    domain: "validation"
    keyword: "additionalProperties"
    unwanted: ["producesx"]
---  END MESSAGES  ---
```

So when I use the **Swagger 2.0 Schema** to validate my **Students Schema** after making it invalid I get an error message. Yay.

This is not the case when I try to use **Students Schema** to validate **Students Response Bad**.

After getting very frustrated I finally decide to use Java Debug to step into the json-schema-validator and json-schema-core libraries.

In the InstanceValidator.class, see screenshots below, I found that for the first **jsonSchemaSwagger.validate(jsonNodeUserSchema, true);** call there were three validators linked to the fullContext object whereas in the second **jsonSchemaUser.validate(jsonNodeData, true);** call there were no validators linked to the fullContext object. Which I'm pretty sure means that no validation will take place.

**First Call**
[image]

**InstanceValidator.class**
[image]

**Three Validators** AdditionalPropertiesValidator, RequiredKeywordValidator and DraftV4TypeValidator
[image]

**Second Call**
[image]

**No Validators**
[image]

**Finally**

And so finally to the question. What calls do I need to make to use the same set of Validators for my second validation call? I.e. how do a create a list of Validators and then get them executed against the JSON Instance data?

Comment: I haven't had time to fully review your question, but if it helps, you should know that the "JSON Schema" used in Swagger is a subset superset of JSON Schema draft-4. It's taken a lot of work, but OpenAPI 3.1 will allow for full and proper JSON Schema. You can't just use a normal JSON Schema validation library to process the schema from a Swagger / OpenAPI document. It has to be aware of such. (Some libraries support both, most do not.)

Comment: @Relequestual understood and one of the things I'll probably try is to use the "definitions" part of the overall schema for verification of the response. For now I'm just trying to get some Validators happening.

Comment: I've also looked at several other libraries including the Atlassian swagger-request-validator and haven't been able to find enough examples to work out how to use them.

Comment: Sorry it's been too long since I've used Java and I have no means to test. Feel free to come join the JSON Schema slack server via the website.

Comment: @Relequestual will do.